# Viewing data, specifically notes, from lost samsung galaxy s5

Tags: data-recovery, notes

I was just curious if it was possible to view notes from the built in app from a Galaxy S5 through another device, namely computer or galaxy S7. I don't have access to the device anymore, but I would like to have the notes that were on it. Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like my gmail account actually saved them in their own folder. Hope this could help anyone from the future!

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#label/Notes

^ where it saved it.